# Can openssh be installed on MSYS?

Tags: openssh, msys

I'm using MSYS in windows 7 and now i need it to provide ssh server service. can openssh be installed in msys like it is in cygwin?

i can find ssh in /msys/bin, and it can be used as ssh client. but no server seems to be installed. how can i install one? i googled a lot but almost every theads leads to openssh in cygwin, that does not apply to my situation.

i compared cygwin and msys and decide to use msys. We need to run some applications both built and supposed to be ran in windows.

what i've tried:

```
mingw-get install mysys-openssh

test@WIN-L3L622JBT6G ~
$ mingw-get install msys-openssh
install: openssh-5.4p1-1-msys-1.0.13-bin.tar.lzm
 installing openssh-5.4p1-1-msys-1.0.13-bin.tar.
install: openssh-5.4p1-1-msys-1.0.13-doc.tar.lzm
 installing openssh-5.4p1-1-msys-1.0.13-doc.tar.
install: openssh-5.4p1-1-msys-1.0.13-lic.tar.lzm
 installing openssh-5.4p1-1-msys-1.0.13-lic.tar.

test@WIN-L3L622JBT6G ~
$ openssh
sh: openssh: command not found
```

the package seems to be installed but i don't know how to find the service. do i need to link it or modify the profile?

Answer (score 8):

The answer would be "NO".

Msys provide ssh client but not ssh server, as it's document indicates.

And Openssh cannot be installed on windows without cygwin. you can install a full cygwin and install openssh in cygwin. It's also feasible to only install partial cygwin.

Comment: https://www.booleanworld.com/get-unix-linux-environment-windows-msys2/ It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Msys is outdated. Use Msys2, which does support sshd: https://www.booleanworld.com/get-unix-linux-environment-windows-msys2/